# Why I don't get compile time error when I am not implementing some method from my interface which is implemented in base class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I have the following code

```
interface IDownload {
  downloadFile(): void;
}

class BaseClass implements IDownload {
  downloadFile(): void {
    console.log('some logic here');
  }
}

class Sub extends BaseClass {

}
```

so my sub class has access to the methods from `BaseClass` because we are extending from that class.

My base class implement some method from interface.

When i try to extend the class and implement again the same interface

```
class Sub extends BaseClass implements IDownload {

}
```

I don't get compile time error that i need to implement the method from IDownload. I guees it is like that because it sees that the base class already implements it.

But i want to have that check also here in my sub class because i want to have the interface contract in the base class where all the methhods will exist on the sub class.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Mark `BaseClass.downloadFile` as `abstract`? That means all descendant classes must override that function...

Comment: But If I mark it as abstract then that method will not have implementation

Comment: Your implementation throws an exception complaining that it hasn't been implemented. That would be a compile-time error if it was `abstract`.

Comment: I updated my question, i removed the throw error, so idea is that the base class is the implementor of the logic

Comment: Can't get a compile time error, what am I doing wrong? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBED2B3EAbTOAE2QG8BYAKGWSJ30KIDFg8IAKASgC5kA3TMCIBuKgF8qVBHjgBnWcgBCciAGEZ85MAC2ABzbaI4BRnoFiZKjTq5zzVhx79BJCtRrIEmELMxsAdAQA5uwA5L6GyMHACMgAFtAQoZyi7hKU6VIaCgDKAK4ARsgQAB6QIEQKyrJq2Vp6BkZgJli2jJaU4pKUIBDYyPkFXP42DMQsbFypQA

Comment: I would suggest simply _not_ extending `BaseClass`

Comment: @Koterpillar i said that i do not get compile time error also

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the implementation in the sub class, why don't you just implement the interface in the sub class?

```
interface IDownload {
  downloadFile(): void;
}

class BaseClass  {

}

class Sub extends BaseClass implements IDownload {
  downloadFile(): void {
    console.log('some logic here');
  }
}
```